# What is the correct term for "secondary IP addresses" handled by a firewall's primary interface?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I have an aging and now-unsupported "ProSAFE" VPN firewall running defense around a /28 block of public IP addresses leased to us by our datacenter.  Our WAN drop is a single ethernet cable.  One of this firewall's most useful features, which I assumed came standard in enterprise-like firewall appliances, is a "secondary addresses" table - basically, the primary WAN interface of the firewall is set to the first IP address in our block, and then I've specified the other 13 in the "WAN Secondary Addresses" table of the router.

When I define the inbound firewall rules, there's a drop-down to choose which destination IP address the packet arrived on, so I can have separate rules for "port 80" such that each of our publicIP:80 results can be NATed to a different private LAN IP (and the rule also gives the option to change the port there too).  I make extensive use of this to publish our different testbed systems so they don't have to be fully exposed or hold a public IP address on their own.

As I'm looking around for replacement firewalls, I can't seem to see any that have a feature which sounds like this, and realized that maybe I don't know what this concept is really called in the networking industry.  My only real hands-on firewall configurating experience is with this particular router and have never had any formal training on it (not counting the many various "home wifi routers" I've had over the years which I wouldn't expect to have anything like this).

Thanks for anyone who can clarify the correct terminology for this type of feature.

Comment: It doesn't sound like anything special. On any (not too old, perhaps) Linux host you can assign multiple addresses on one interface, and you can 1:1 NAT / port forward any way you like. I don't think there's a special term for that but "support multiple address to assigned be on one / the WAN interface" (with that said,  any vendor can make it sound special by naming it however it likes, e.g. IP Megamix / UltraWAN).

Comment: Features that are related / facilitate similar goal includes ARP proxy / AnyIP (I'm not sure if the latter is a proper / official term.)

Answer (score -1):

The term you're looking for is "NAT firewall" or "Firewall NAT".

The "NAT" stands for
[Network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation),
defined as:

> Network address translation (NAT) is a method of mapping an IP address space into another by modifying network address information in the IP header of packets while they are in transit across a traffic routing device. The technique was originally used to avoid the need to assign a new address to every host when a network was moved, or when the upstream Internet service provider was replaced, but could not route the network's address space. It has become a popular and essential tool in conserving global address space in the face of IPv4 address exhaustion. One Internet-routable IP address of a NAT gateway can be used for an entire private network.

You will need to search for a firewall product that does NAT.
These firewalls are usually commercial in nature.
Pretty much all the top providers on the market have it:
NordVPN,
IPVanish,
VyprVPN,
PIA,
PureVPN.

A sample reference:
[What Is a NAT Firewall, Why Is It Important, and Why Do So Many VPNs Use It?](https://www.technadu.com/nat-firewall/100829/).

Comment: Thanks harrymc - I think it's a step beyond NAT though; even the basic home routers and simple stuff do NAT (ie, the single public address:port inbound routed to a lan address:port).  The more-specific term I'm looking for describes when NAT is supported for a list of multiple public IPs.  I was pretty shocked when the sales engineer with TPL/Omada confirmed they could *not* do virtual/secondary IPs, because that looked like a very enterprise-like system and definitely supports basic NAT; that's when I started to question my terminology. Thanks for the feedback...

Comment: Found at least one which actually uses the same terminology that our old one did: the Watchguard calls this feature "Secondary Address" in their GUI.  Weird thing is that it's singular, implying you could only have one, but it does let you add multiple.

Comment: NAT as done by most commercial routers implies a single public address, which is not the same thing. It takes a professional router to do better.

Answer (score -1):

If all of the assigned addresses were used for SNAT/masquerading of outbound traffic, then "NAT pool" would be a relevant term, but that doesn't seem to apply in your case.

I would say there is *no* specific term for what you're doing; the router literally just has multiple IP addresses on the interface. You could call them "secondary addresses" or sometimes "IP aliasing" (seems to come from Cisco terminal servers), but it is not exactly an Enterprise Feature.

Quite the opposite, being able to have multiple IPv4 addresses per interface is standard in Linux and BSDs, and even on Windows (though a bit less useful there). For IPv6, having multiple addresses is part of the baseline spec.

Your typical home wireless router, with its core being usually based around Linux and iptables, could also achieve the same thing as the ProSAFE – indeed some of them *do* allow configuring multiple addresses and do expose the "destination IP" field in their NAT rules. For those which don't, it's just missing from the web interface (possibly for product differentiation reasons), but the capability is still there in the kernel.

(It is similar to the routing table – many "home wifi routers" don't offer the ability to define custom routes, but every single one of them has that ability under the hood, because they're all running Linux and it's such an integral part of the IP stack that it would literally take effort to rip it out.)

---

I would say however that there's probably some false sense of security in NATing certain ports instead of directly routing the public IP address to the web server. If your server did have a public IP address, it would still be behind the firewall – and if that firewall only allowed dst port 80 through, then there would be no difference in exposure between it and a NATed port 80. A client could still connect to the same webserver software, send the same HTTP requests, etc.